# SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) is not visible in Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: eclipse

SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) is not visible in Elipse Marketplace. I see only Spring Tools (aka Spring IDE and Spring Tool suite). What should I do to add SpringSource Tool Suite to Marketplace to installation will pissible?

[image]

---

Yes, I have installed Spring Tools but no SpringSource, and I need Spring Source Tools. When I cklick on inscription "2 matches. Browse for more solution" Eclips opens web side and I see Spring Source Tools like in attached picture, but I don't know how to add it to Marketplace and then install. Thank you for your help :) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYpZI.png)

Comment: You've found what you're looking for: ... aka _SpringSource Tool Suite (STS)_, but it seems you have already installed it.

Comment: Yes, I have installed Spring Tools but no SpringSource, and I need Spring Source Tools. When I cklick on inscription "2 matches. Browse for more solution" Eclips opens web side and I see Spring Source Tools like in attached picture, but I don't know how to add it to Marketplace and then install. Thank you for your help :)